# Server-Side Code to Execute Based on a Time Range

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, time

We have a Try/Catch block of code in our web application to trap a certain exception.  What we want to do with this exception depends on the current time.  If it is between 4:30PM and 3:00AM we will want to send an email, otherwise we will throw the exception.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

```
Try
    'Yada
Catch ex as WebException
    Dim Time As DateTime = DateTime.Now

    'Not sure where to go from here!
End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is between those times every day the easiest thing would be to check to see if now is before 3:00 AM on the current day, or if now is after 4:30 PM on the current day. That would then cover both the 4:30 PM to 12 midnight and midnight to 3 am time spans.

**Edited** by Josh Stodola to add code:

```
  Dim Time As DateTime = DateTime.Now
  Dim Low As New Date(Time.Year, Time.Month, Time.Day, 16, 30, 0)
  Dim High As New Date(Time.Year, Time.Month, Time.Day, 3, 0, 0)

  If Time > Low OrElse Time < High Then
      'Send Email
  Else
      Throw Ex
  End If
```

Comment: Yes but I decided to remove the exact code on how, I started wondering if this was someones homework assignment